# How to use IF & IN inside snowflake stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write a stored procedure in Snowflake.

First thing I want to check the condition and then only execute the real code.

I need help in using `if` condition to check the condition is satisfied with in 2 values.

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.SPNAME()
 RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
 LANGUAGE SQL
 COMMENT='user-defined procedure'
 EXECUTE AS OWNER
 AS BEGIN

 IF    dayname(dateadd(hour, 10, convert_timezone('America/Chicago', current_timestamp()))) in ('Sat', 'Sun') 
 THEN
    RETURN 'Not Thursday'
 END IF;

END;
```

Can you please correct me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake requires that condition is enclosed with `()` and each statement must end with semicolon:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SPNAME()
 RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
 LANGUAGE SQL
 COMMENT='user-defined procedure'
 EXECUTE AS OWNER
 AS 
BEGIN

  IF (dayname(dateadd(hour,10,convert_timezone('America/Chicago',current_timestamp()))) 
     IN ('Sat','Sun')) THEN
   RETURN 'Not Thursday';
  END IF;

END;
```

Output:

[image]